# How to get data from database with kohana?

Tags: php, mysql, database, frameworks, kohana

Hy!

I configured the modules/database/database.php file. In controller/index.php I have:

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER By id DESC');
```

Using phpmyadmin, I created two blog posts, but the script doesn't seem to get them from the database. I don't see any errors and also the blog posts are not visible.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English, I am a schoolboy from Latvia and I'm learning English. :)

Comment: Can we see the entire contents of your controller/action which should handle this request? The problem is not coming from this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read documentation: "Once you are done building, you can execute the query using execute() and use the results."

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER By id DESC')->execute();
```

Now you can use foreach.

```
foreach($query as $item){  ..  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use Query Builder where it's possible to accidently avoid SQL injection in the future:

```
$query = DB::select()
            ->from('posts')
            ->order_by('id', 'DESC')
            ->execute();
```